# How can I format the input text on Google Translate so that the translation doesn't change person names?

Tags: text-generation, machine-translation, nlp, google

When I have some texts to translate, I notice that sometimes, [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) messes up person names. E.g.:

> The interview went well. Cherry is good.

[becomes](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=The%20interview%20went%20well.%20Cherry%20is%20good):

> L'entretien s'est bien passé. La cerise est bonne.

which is not good because the person name "Cherry" was changed into "La cerise" (not to mention that "est bonne" would certainly warrant a trip to the HR). "La cerise" means "The cherry" (the fruit).

[image]

How can I format the input text on Google Translate or configure Google Translate so that the translation doesn't change person  names?

Comment: Regarding the close vote about lack of clarity, please tell me what I should clarify

Comment: I'm sorry. I voted to close as, at first sight, it looked to me to require more details. Later I realized that I needed to prepare myself to explain what was missing. While working on this, I decided to retract my close vote primarily based on consideration of the GenAI Stack Exchange's current stage: it's a young community that might benefit from questions like this, assuming that the community will stay actively participating by providing rich answers, comments and debates (using the [chat] and [meta]).

Comment: @Wicket Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Google Translate, the Web app, doesn't offer input formatting options.

Try the UI interactive elements:

- Click the translation; clicking on it will show a dropdown offering other alternative translations.
- "Look up details" links; clicking them will open a sidebar, then select a word. The sidebar will show information about the selected text.
- Thumbs up/down button; clicking on it will open a pop-up to submit translation feedback.
- Send feedback link: clicking it will open a UI element guiding the user to submit feedback to Google.
- Contribute: clicking on it will open a UI element that will guide to user to contribute to making Google Translate more accurate.

For details of the above options, go to the [Google Translate Help micro site](https://support.google.com/translate). It includes tabs for Help Center, Community and Announcements.

---

#### Workarounds

As with most tools, Google Translate's effectiveness depends on the circumstances and user skills.

Try alternative wordings to translate the text if the circumstances and your skills allow that. As the OP mentioned in [their answer to this question](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/316/12), adding `Miss` before the `Cherry` help Google Translate to "understand" that, in this case, this word refers to a *human female person name* instead of a *fruit-type name*.

Other things to try

- Enclose the words to not be translated by characters like underscore, `_`, open/closing curly brackets, `{`, `}`.

  Using underscore:
  [image: Google Translate using underscore]

  Using curly brackets:
  [image: Google Translate using curly brackets]

It's worth noting that this method only works sometimes. Probably the most reliable method will be to replace the word that we don't want to translate with a placeholder, i.e., one or multiple underscores; then, if it will be needed to transfer the translation to a message or document, replace the placeholder with the corresponding word.

---

You might be interested in the translation services from Google. Start studying from https://cloud.google.com/translate.

In the past, Google offered a sister app, Google Translator Toolkit. It allowed users to make advanced translation tasks. Unfortunately, this tool was deprecated in 2019. Ref. [Google Translator Toolkit Has Shut Down](https://support.google.com/answer/9464390).

Related

- [Prohibit the translation of pieces of text in Google Translate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52668/)

Answer (score 1):

One can add Miss/Mister in front of the person names, which helps the system identify which token is a person name.

Example:

> The interview went well. Miss Cherry is good.

becomes

> L'entretien s'est bien passé.  Mlle Cherry est bonne.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: While this might work as a particular workaround and might be extrapolated by some users to other use cases, answers that explain why could provide more specific guidance. Also, you might include other use cases. I.E. in this case, the fruit name is also used as a person name. What workaround might be used for pet names? What about city names? Ref: [answer].

Comment: @Wicket thanks, OP only asked about person names. Answer to why is because  adding Miss/Mister helps the system identify which token is a person name.

Comment: I respectfully offer a suggestion that perhaps your response could encompass a broader scope of scenarios, even if the question pertains to a specific case. Please take my previous comment and this one as friendly guidance rather than a rigid requirement to alter your answer.

Comment: @Wicket got it, fully agreed, but I don't have a solution for other named entities :(

Comment: I added another workaround to my [answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/314/12) that might be helpful when it's impossible to change the text's wording to be translated. TL;DR enclose the name / word that should not be translated using underscore or curly brackets. Underscore might be a slightly better option to automate their removal except for when the text uses underscore, i.e., for markdown.

Comment: @Wicket oh nice that a good idea! In the past I sometimes made intentional typos in the person names but the underscore solution is much neater

Comment: *much neater and much more reliable. So far the  underscore solution has worked all the time in my use cases.

Comment: FYI, with more practice, I did notice a few cases where the underscore solution didn't work, so I posted the question on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173434/18147. But it worked in >90% of cases I've tried.